# PE 101 explanation of addresses to windows api calls

Tags: winapi, assembly, hex, call, disassembly

I am trying to build a program that will give more information about a file and possibly a disassembler. I looked at https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE101 to get more information and after reading it a few times I am understanding most of it. the part I don't understand is the call addresses to windows api. for example how did he know that the instruction call [0x402070] was an api call to messagebox? I understand how to count the addresses to the strings and the 2 push commands to strings make sense, but not the dll part.

I guess what I am trying to say is I don't understand the part that says "imports structures"
(the part I drew a box around in yellow) If any one could please explain to me how 0x402068 points to exitProcess and 0x402070 points to MessageBoxA, this would really help me. thanks
[image]

Comment: Did you download PE101.zip and inspect the sources also? They are quite unusual.

Answer (score 2):

**Loader** (a part of Windows OS) "patches up" the **Import Address Table** (IAT) before starting the sample program, that's when the real addresses of the library procedures appear in the memory locations 0x402068 and 0x402068. Please note that imports reside in section *nobits* in **simple.asm**:

```
section nobits vstart=IMAGEBASE + 2 * SECTIONALIGN align=FILEALIGN
```

The section with imports after load starts at **virtual address** (IMAGEBASE=400000h)+2*(SECTIONALIGN=1000h)=0x402000 .

The yasm source of the example is quite unusual and the diagram is also not the best place to learn **PE format** from. Please start by reading [Wikipedia:Portable_Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) first (a short article). It has links to the [full documents](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/pecoff.doc), so I will only make some short notes here.

You might also want to use the [Cheat Engine](http://cheatengine.org/) to inspect the sample. Launch simple.exe, then attach to the process with **Cheat Engine**, press <kbd>Memory View</kbd>, then menu **Tools**->**Dissect PE headers**, then button <kbd>Info</kbd>, look at tab **Imports**. In the memory dump, go to address 00402000 (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> *00402000* <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

> 00402068: **E4 39 BE 75** 00 00 00 00 **69 5F 47 77** 00 00 00 00 6B 65 72 6E 65 6C 33 32 2E

Note the values at these locations

- 00402068: 0x75BE39E4 (on my computer) = the address of KERNEL32.ExitProcess
- 00402070: 0x77475F69 (in my case only) = the address of user32.MessageBoxA

Notice the text **"kernel32.dll user32.dll"** right after them. Now look at the hexdump of **simple.exe** (I would use [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com/index.php?l=en)) and spot the same location before strings **"kernel32.dll user32.dll"**. The values there are

> ```
> 0000000450: 69 74 50 72 6F 63 65 73 │ 73 00 00 00 4D 65 73 73  itProcess   Mess
> 0000000460: 61 67 65 42 6F 78 41 00 │ 4C_20_00_00 00 00 00 00  ageBoxA L
> 0000000470: 5A_20_00_00 00 00 00 00 │ 6B 65 72 6E 65 6C 33 32  Z       kernel32
> 0000000480: 2E 64 6C 6C 00 75 73 65 │ 72 33 32 2E 64 6C 6C 00  .dll user32.dll
> ```

- 0000000468: 0x0000204C — the **Relative Virtual Address** of dw 0;db 'ExitProcess', 0
- 0000000470: 0x0000205A — the **Relative Virtual Address** of dw 0;db 'MessageBoxA', 0

The loader has changed these values from what they were in the file after loading into memory. The Microsoft document pecoff.doc says about it:

> 6.4.4. **Import Address Table**
>   The structure and content of the Import Address Table are identical to that of the Import Lookup Table, until the file is bound. During binding, the entries in the Import Address Table are overwritten with the 32-bit (or 64-bit for PE32+) addresses of the symbols being imported: these addresses are the actual memory addresses of the symbols themselves (although technically, they are still called “virtual addresses”). The processing of binding is typically performed by the loader.

Comment: The IAT contains the names of the DLLs and functions being imported.  When calling a DLL function, the app's code performs a `CALL` to the memory address that the loader has stored in the IAT slot for that function. So when your disassembler sees a `CALL` to a memory address that is retrieved from the IAT, it can retrieve the DLL+function names from the IAT for display purposes instead of displaying the memory address.